# ggplot geom_path connect lines separated by scale_size_manual

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a geom_path that is combined with scale_size_manual for alternating line width.

(My initial problem were the connecting lines between the sections which I could solve with `group =` thanks to this post: [geom_path lines "closing" ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38505412/r-geom-path-lines-closing-sometimes-how-to-keep-them-open))

Now I'd like to close the gaps between the sections (at the blue circles in the plot). Is there an easy way to solve this? (Except for drawing segments from every `last(p)` to every `first(p)`.) I don't care if the connections are thin or thick lines.

[image: geom_path_test]

Here's a small portion of my data:

```
dat <- structure(list(
  x = c(10.96, 10.99, 11.01, 11.03, 11.04, 11.04, 
        11.05, 11.05, 11.04, 11.04, 11.04, 11.03, 11.03, 11.03, 11.04, 
        11.04, 11.04, 11.05, 11.05, 11.06, 11.06, 11.07, 11.08, 11.09, 
        11.11, 11.13, 11.16, 11.19, 11.24, 11.29, 11.34, 11.4, 11.46, 
        11.52, 11.58, 11.63, 11.68, 11.73, 11.77, 11.81, 11.84, 11.88, 
        11.92, 11.96, 12, 12.05, 12.1, 12.16, 12.21, 12.27, 12.33, 12.4, 
        12.46, 12.51, 12.57, 12.62, 12.67, 12.71, 12.75, 12.78, 12.8, 
        12.81, 12.81, 12.8, 12.77, 12.74, 12.69, 12.64, 12.58, 12.52, 
        12.46),
  y = c(1.31, 1.33, 1.36, 1.39, 1.43, 1.47, 1.52, 1.57, 
        1.64, 1.71, 1.78, 1.85, 1.93, 2, 2.07, 2.13, 2.18, 2.22, 2.25, 
        2.26, 2.26, 2.24, 2.2, 2.14, 2.07, 1.99, 1.9, 1.81, 1.72, 1.64, 
        1.57, 1.52, 1.49, 1.47, 1.48, 1.51, 1.56, 1.62, 1.69, 1.76, 1.84, 
        1.91, 1.98, 2.03, 2.08, 2.11, 2.13, 2.13, 2.12, 2.1, 2.07, 2.03, 
        1.98, 1.93, 1.88, 1.82, 1.77, 1.71, 1.66, 1.6, 1.55, 1.51, 1.46, 
        1.42, 1.39, 1.37, 1.35, 1.34, 1.34, 1.35, 1.36), 
  p = c(0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
  s = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L)),
  row.names = c(NA, -71L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And here's the code I'm using:

```
plo <- ggplot() +
  geom_path(data = dat, 
            aes(x = x, y = y, size = if_else(p == 0, "A", "B"), group = s)) +
  scale_size_manual(name = NULL, values = c("A" = 0.3, "B" = 1.5)) +
  # the follwing elements are just here to explain the question
  geom_point(aes(x = (dat$x[5] + dat$x[6]) / 2, y = (dat$y[5] + dat$y[6]) / 2), shape = 1, color = "blue", size = 8) +
  geom_point(aes(x = (dat$x[48] + dat$x[49]) / 2, y = (dat$y[48] + dat$y[49]) / 2), shape = 1, color = "blue", size = 8) +
  geom_point(aes(x = (dat$x[61] + dat$x[62]) / 2, y = (dat$y[61] + dat$y[62]) / 2), shape = 1, color = "blue", size = 8) +
  coord_fixed() + theme_bw()
plo
```

Comment: what happens if you group everything together, something like `aes(group = "1", ...)`

Comment: Nate's suggestion would solve the issue. Also you could use `ggforce::geom_link2(aes(group = 1, ...), ...)` to connect with a variable width line.

Comment: Thanks, `group = "1"` works fine. I'll give `geom_link2` as well!